# Determining if an undirected graph is a tree

Tags: graph-algorithm, graph-theory

I found that a depth-first approach that finds back edges is a solution. However, is there any other way to determine if an undirected graph is a tree?

More specifically, how would I use the notion of neighborhood (of a node or set of nodes) to formulate such an algorithm? Can I find and count cycles?

Comment: [What I should do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach comes from the definition of graph which is tree.

1. Connected and
2. has no cycles (acyclic)

For first a simple bfs will give you the answer and if 1 is true then just count the number of edges, if they are n-1, then its acyclic.

**2nd** is very easy, just count the edges.

**1st**

- mark all nodes as unvisited
- for every node `c`, if this node is unvisited

  - create a new empty set of nodes, the current component
  - enqueue the this node for traversal
  - while there is any node `t` enqueued

    - remove this node from the queue
    - mark every unvisited neighbor as open and enqueue it for traversal
    - mark this node as traversed
    - add this node to the current component
  - close the current component, and add it to the set of components